# How do java Imports work (swing)?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, import, package

So I tried to create an empty border and was required to import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

However I had already imported javax.swing.*;

How come I was required to import the prior import? Doesn't the .* import everything from the swing package.

My source code is listed below:

```
   import javax.swing.*;
   import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

   import java.awt.*;
  /*
public class Gui extends JFrame {

//row1
JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
JButton play = new JButton("Play");

//row2
JPanel row2 = new JPanel();
JLabel option = new JLabel("Guess: ", JLabel.RIGHT);
JTextField text1 = new JTextField("0");
JTextField text2 = new JTextField("0");
JTextField text3 = new JTextField("0");

//row3
JPanel row3 = new JPanel();
JLabel answerL = new JLabel("Answer: ", JLabel.RIGHT);
JTextField answerB = new JTextField("", 0);
*/
public Gui(){
/*  super("Guess My Number");
    setSize(500, 800);
    GridLayout masterLayout = new GridLayout(4, 1);
    setLayout(masterLayout);


    FlowLayout layout1 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT);
    row1.setLayout(layout1);
    row1.add(reset);
    row1.add(play);
    add(row1);


    GridLayout layout2 = new GridLayout(1, 4, 30, 30);
    row2.setLayout(layout2);*/
    row2.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,100,0,200));
    /*row2.add(option);
    row2.add(text1);
    row2.add(text2);
    row2.add(text3);
    add(row2);

    GridLayout layout3 = new GridLayout(1,1, 10, 10);
    row3.setLayout(layout3);
    row3.add(answerL);
    row3.add(answerB);
    add(row3);


    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Gui game = new Gui();
}
}
 */
```

Comment: Are you wondering why you had to import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder; and javax.swing.*?

Comment: Precisely, why do I have to separately import them, shouldn't javax.swing.*  contain the imports from the border class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no relationship between nested packages in Java.

`javax.swing.*` will only import classes directly found in `javax.swing`, `javax.swing.border` is considered a different unrelated package altogether from a language standpoint.

Comment: Is this analogous to java.awt.*; and java.awt.event.*;

Comment: @RamandeepSinghBedi Yep, those are two different packages as well, the nesting of the names is a programming convention that might mean a lot to the programmer, but not to the code.

Comment: *"..might mean a lot to the programmer, but not to the code."*  That's a good way to explain it.  :)